# Bash script to compare ASCII values

Tags: bash, test, ascii

what is the wrong?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

REF_FILE_NUM="000000010000001900000052"

for id in `ls -1 dir` ;
 do
 FILE_NUM=${id:0:24}
 echo "FILE_NUM: $FILE_NUM ; REF_FILE_NUM: $REF_FILE_NUM"

 if [[ "$FILE_NUM" < "$REF_FILE_NUM" ]]
 then
    echo "$FILE_NUM lt $REF_FILE_NUM"
    echo ""
 else
    echo "$FILE_NUM gt $REF_FILE_NUM"
    echo ""
 fi

 done
```

```
freebsd# ./test.sh
FILE_NUM: 0000000100000019000000FF ; REF_FILE_NUM: 000000010000001900000052
0000000100000019000000FF gt 000000010000001900000052

FILE_NUM: 0000000100000020000000FF ; REF_FILE_NUM: 000000010000001900000052
0000000100000020000000FF gt 000000010000001900000052

FILE_NUM: 0000000100000021000000FF ; REF_FILE_NUM: 000000010000001900000052
0000000100000021000000FF gt 000000010000001900000052
```

Comment: I fail to see the point FF ending values are greater then 52 ending one.

Comment: Indeed; what is wrong? It looks OK to me. `20` and `21` *are* greater than `19`. (1) Please explain what the script is supposed to be doing. (2) Please tell us what your filenames are. (Do this explicitly, separately from the output of your script.) (3) Explain what output you expect, and why. (4) Explain why you believe that the actual output is wrong. (5) Your filenames have a lot of zeroes in them, and are hard to read. Repeat your test with short names like `11952`, `119FF`, `120FF` and `121FF`. … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: I apologize to everyone, the script is really OK, but I was a little tired yesterday and slip up.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

That all boils down to

```
[[ F > 5 ]] && [[ 2 > 1 ]]
```

In ASCII, `F` is 70 (0x46), while `5` is 53 (0x35).

What output would you expect and why?